# Как спарсить 2 значения с 1 строки?

Tags: c, строки

Имеется текстовый файл:

```
Evg:03afk
FKspks:kckz0d0a2a
ggkgk03:Lkfk392a
```

Парсить нужно в разные массивы(2 массива на 2 значения).

```
char WorkingDir[ MAX_PATH ] , txtPath[ MAX_PATH ];

GetCurrentDirectory( _countof( WorkingDir ) , WorkingDir );

sprintf_s( txtPath , "%s\\list.txt" , WorkingDir  );

FILE* fp = fopen( txtPath , "r" );
if( fp )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )// 1000 строк
    {
        /*
        first[i] = первое значение
        second[i] = второе значение(после : )
        */
    }
    fclose( fp );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего - раз у вас четкая структура с разделением двоеточием - найти двоеточие и записать кусок до и после. Считываем строку в буфер `buf`, раз уж у вас голый C, а потом -

```
char * с = strchr(buf,':'); 
// Стоит проверить, найдено ли...

*c = 0;
strcpy(first[i],buf);
strcpy(second[i],c+1);
```

(Я считаю, что `first[i]` и `second[i]` - выделенные массивы символов достаточного размера).

Примерно так...

Comment: про чтение в буфер не совсем понял

Comment: Ну, знаете... Это уже перебор - если вы умеете открыть фaйл, то и прочесть из него строку должны уметь... `fgets` и https://en.cppreference.com/w/ вам в помощь.

Comment: Этому научился, теперь ошибка в другом , конкретно в `*c = 0;`

Comment: Это просто "разрезание" строки. В С строка заканчивается нулевым символом, так что теперь первая строка - то, что было до двоеточия (которое теперь 0), а вторая начинается со следующего за ним символа - `c+1`.

Comment: @33cc00, убрать '\n` из второго слова после `fgets()` не забудьте