# Не получается считывать текстовый файл

Tags: c, lua

```
char* first[ 15 ];
char* second[ 15 ];
char WorkingDir[ MAX_PATH ] , txtPath[ MAX_PATH ];

GetCurrentDirectory( _countof( WorkingDir ) , WorkingDir );

sprintf_s( txtPath , "%s\\list.txt" , WorkingDir );

FILE* fp = fopen( txtPath , "r" );

if( fp )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ )
    {
        char buf[ 128 ];
        fgets( buf , 128 , fp );
        char * c;
        c = strchr( buf , ':' );

        *c = 0;

        strcpy( first[ i ] , buf ); 
        strcpy( second[ i ] , c + 1 );
    }
    fclose( fp );
}
```

В итоге идет ошибка в ходе работы, нужно считывать каждую линию и записывать 2 значения

`prfas:123asd
asddkdk:fg1g1g1
h021k2k:lkfkk00`

Вот как это работает на Lua

```
local first = {}
local second = {}
local count = 0
local txt = io.open("txtfile.txt","r") 
if txt ~= nil then 
    for str in txt:lines() do 
        count = count + 1 
        pstr[count] = str 
    end 

    for i = 1, #pstr do 
        if pstr[i]:match("(%S+):(%S+)") ~= nil then 
            first[i], second[i] = pstr[i]:match("(%S+):(%S+)")
        end 
    end
 txt:close()
end
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86914/discussion-on-question-by-33cc00-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, от применения единственной перегруженной функции `sprintf_s` этот код не становится кодом С++, он становится кодом С с ошибкой :)

Во-вторых, что я писал вам в ответе на предыдущий вопрос? [Цитирую](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/918044/195342):

> (Я считаю, что first[i] и second[i] - выделенные массивы символов достаточного размера).

Где эта достаточная память? У вас нет никакой, и что еще хуже - у вас `first[i]` и `second[i]` указывают не пойми куда!

Если бы - подчеркиваю - если бы - это был код на C++, то мы бы имели

```
string first[ 15 ], second[15];
```

и тогда действительно можно было бы вместо

```
strcpy( first[ i ] , buf ); 
strcpy( second[ i ] , c + 1 );
```

писать просто

```
first[i] = buf;
second[i] = c+1;
```

Но раз это код на C, то надо либо выделять перед `strcpy` память -

```
first[i] = malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
second[i] = malloc(strlen(c+1)+1);
```

либо воспользоваться `strdup`:

```
first[i] = strdup(buf);
second[i] = strdup(c+1);
```

либо сразу выделить достаточную память:

```
char first[15][128];
char second[15][128];
```

и в первых двух случаях не забыть потом освободить эту память.

И запишите свой

```
sprintf_s( txtPath , "%s\\list.txt" , WorkingDir );
```

как

```
sprintf_s( txtPath , MAX_PATH, "%s\\list.txt" , WorkingDir );
```

и смените тэг C++ на C. У вас нет ничего от С++ в вашем коде - это голый С со всеми его подходами и идиомами. С, компилируемый по умолчанию (по недоразумению, скорее) в режиме С++.

Comment: Вот как сделал
`char first[ 15 ][ 128 ];
char second[ 15 ][ 128 ];
 char WorkingDir[ MAX_PATH ] , txtPath[ MAX_PATH ];

 GetCurrentDirectory( _countof( WorkingDir ) , WorkingDir );

 sprintf_s( txtPath , MAX_PATH , "%s\\list.txt" , WorkingDir );

 FILE* fp = fopen( txtPath , "r" );

 if( fp )
 {
  for( int i = 0; i < 15; i++ ) // 15 строк
  {
   char buf[ 128 ];
   fgets( buf , 128 , fp );
   char * c;
   c = strchr( buf , ':' );

   *c = 0;
   if( c && buf )
   {
    strcpy( first[ i ] , buf );
    strcpy( second[ i ] , c + 1 );
   }
  }
  fclose( fp );
 }
`

Comment: Вывожу так:


`for(auto i =0; i<= 15;i++)
cout << first[i] << endl;
`


Вывод:
`asdasd
fafa
`

С текстовика вида:
`asdasd:fafa`

Comment: Вот тут - https://ideone.com/BuF08T - работающий вариант. Единственное,  я был вынужден 1. убрать `sprintf_s` - gcc о нем не знал, 2. дописать создание файла программно - а потом его открывать. Можете взять текст к себе и убедиться...